# How to handle Querystring in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a js code:

```
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("Button1").onclick = function() {
            var t1 = document.getElementById("Text1").value;
            var t2 = document.getElementById("Text2").value;

            document.URL = 'myurl?t1=' + t1 + '&t2' + t2;
         }
    }
```

Here i am adding t1,t2 as query param..now my question is lets say i have entered some data in Textbox1 but not in textbox2, in that case the url I am getting is 
`'myurl?t1=' + value of textbox1 + '&t2' + This will be blank;`
I want to make it dynamic, i.e.if there is not value in Textbox2 then I dont want to append queryparam t2, same goes for t1 also..isit possible?

Comment: It won't break the url if the value of one of them is empty. And change document.URL to window.location or the browser won't open that page (FF)

Comment: yep.but its just an example, not the real application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.URL = 'myurl?t1=' + t1 + (''!=t2 ? '&t2' + t2 : '');
```

simply, use (? true:false) logic construction to test if var t2 is empty or not. If it's not empty add to document.URL `'&t2'+t2`, otherwise pass nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `if` clauses.

```
var url = "";
if (t1)
    url += "&t1=" + encodeURIComponent(t1);
if (t2)
    url += "&t2=" + encodeURIComponent(t2);
document.URL = "myurl" + url.replace(/^&/, "?");
```

Or even better, **don't use JavaScript at all**. Just use a form with `action="get"`. This is exactly what they're for.

Comment: @Tomas: Fixed. By the way, you have enough reputation to edit other peoples' posts yourself, so you can go ahead and make corrections like these yourself if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

document.URL = 'myurl?t1=' + t1 + (t2?'&t2' + t2:'');

Answer (score 0):

I personally use this function for creating queries:

```
function CreateQuery(URL, D) {
    // Returns a URL in format "URL?Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2"
    var L = [];
    for (var k in D) {
        if (!D.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue;
        var eK = encodeURIComponent(k);
        var eV = encodeURIComponent(D[Key]);
        L.push(eK+'='+eV);
    }
    if (L.length)
        return URL+'?'+L.join('&');
    return URL;
}
```

To use it, you might go e.g:

```
var q = {};
if (t1) q['t1'] = t1;
if (t2) q['t2'] = t2;
window.location = CreateQuery('myurl', a);
```

(Or use a [`<form>`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), which is probably still the better option as another user has suggested :-)